# How can I delete vertices in a network based on attribute values using R package Network or similar

Tags: r, network-analysis

I'm trying to build a network from a matrix such that I can graph the full network or only a subset of vertices. I've been using the Network package in R
and have created a toy network where I've added two attributes to the vertices: 'year' and 'topic'. Then I plot the network such that topics are coloured differently.

```
library(network)
B = matrix(c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0), nrow=5, ncol=5)
b<-network(B)
b %v% "topic"=c("Surveillance","Inspection efficiency","Surveillance","Inspection efficiency","Surveillance")
b %v% "year"=c(2006,2006,2007,2007,2007)
ggnet2(b,node.size = 10, node.color = "topic", edge.size = 1, edge.color = "grey",palette = "Set2",label=c("1101","908","1107","601","604"),label.size = 3)`
```

What I'd like to do is plot this same network but only for vertices with the value '2006' for the attribute 'year'. Any suggestions would be welcome

Answer (score 0):

Subset the network with the `%s%` operator.

```
library(network)
B = matrix(c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0), nrow=5, ncol=5)
b<-network(B)
b %v% "topic"=c("Surveillance","Inspection efficiency","Surveillance","Inspection efficiency","Surveillance")
b %v% "year"=c(2006,2006,2007,2007,2007)

b2006 <- b %s% which(b %v% "year"==2006)
```

Comment: That is a **perfect** solution! Thank you very much!